# When i use Array.splice(), it's like i'm using Array.slice()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i just noticed that when i use Array.splice() it's like i'm using Array.slice(),

So when i type`[0, 1, 2, 3].splice(0, 2)` it returns `[0, 1]`? (yes i am shure that i'm typing `splice` not `slice`)

So basicly:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(0, 2);
returns [0, 1]?

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].splice(3, 1);
returns [3]?

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].slice(0, 2);
returns [0, 1]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].slice(3, 1);
returns [3]
```

Why does this happen?
It's supposed to remove the specified objects right?

Comment: `splice()` can replace items with other items, altering the input array. `slice()` just takes from an array without altering it. The docs must explain this better.

Comment: Look at what the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)...."*Returns
An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.*" It is not returning the altered array as you assume it is.

Comment: Shouldn't it work like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript ?

Comment: See MDN's [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: The second argument of Array.splice() is the delete count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the same thing, sure, except slice does not mutate the original array. 
Splice, on the other hand returns what was removed from the original array.

Answer (score 0):

`slice` takes a copy of a section of the array and returns it.

`splice` removes a section of the array and returns it.  An optional parameter allows replacing those elements with others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** method modifies the contents of the array on which you are calling.

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing
>   existing elements and/or adding new elements.

Whereas, the **[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** method returns the new array copy from the given range of index.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object.

Answer (score 0):

- `splice()` replaces items with other items, altering the input array.
- `slice()` just takes from an array without altering it.

Since you're not using a variable as input, you'll never see the difference. But try this:

```
a = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
a.splice(2, 2)
> [6, 7]
a
> [4, 5, 8]
```

`a` has changed. That's `splice()`

The real power comes from substitution/replacement:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a.splice(2, 2, 500, 600)
> [5, 6]
a
> [3, 4, 500, 600, 7]
```

If you have an array of items to 'splice' into  the array, you have to use `.apply`:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = [500, 600]
>  [500, 600]
a.splice.apply(a, [2, 2].concat(b))
> [5, 6]
a
> [3, 4, 500, 600, 7]
```

Or make your own function that does that more readable.

You can also splice-add items into an array, by making the 2nd argument 0: `a.splice(2, 0, 500, 600)`.

[You can read all this, and more, in the docs!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)